# Wrong output for C# linking to SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

Below is the output I get after I press the button although the `EmployeeNumber` and `DOB` do exist in my SQL Server database.

I had tried many times and can't figure out the problem causing the wrong output.

[image: Output from C#]

Thank you for helping !

C# code:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FirstConnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spEmployeeC", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", txtEmployee.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtPassword.Text);

    //cmd.IsValid

    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (txtEmployee.Text == "@Employee" && txtPassword.Text == "@DOB")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + txtEmployee.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Username or Password you entered is incorrect. Please try again");
    }
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spEmployeeC
    @Employee INT,
    @DOB DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    DECLARE @Employee_check INT;
    DECLARE @Password_check DATE;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Employee_Table 
    WHERE [EMPLOYEE_NUM] = @Employee AND [DOB] = @DOB
END
```

Comment: Firstly: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Secondly: You don't do anything with the result of the stored procedure execution. You ar only checking if the username text box contains the text "@Employee"

Comment: @DavidG Hi David! Thank you for your sharing , is there any better way to improve my code? :)

Comment: I don't want to sound nasty, but this is very basic C#. I would suggest running through some tutorials before you ask more questions here.

Comment: @DavidG i see, sorry for disturbing tho. I m just start my C# code today. Well thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would be better:

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployee.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must supply an Employee Number");
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must supply a Password");
            return;
        }

        if (IsAuthenticated())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + txtEmployee.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Username or Password you entered is incorrect. Please try again");
        };
    }

    private bool IsAuthenticated()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spValidateCredentials", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEmployee.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtPassword.Text);
            conn.Open();
            return ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0);
        }
    }
```

Also maybe change the Stored Procedure to return a count of the records:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spValidateCredentials]
    @Employee INT,
    @DOB DATE
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Employee_Table 
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUM=@Employee 
       AND DOB=@DOB
END
```